# Scala Promise Clarification

Tags: scala

Quick question if in Scala you where to succeeded a promise like so;

```
 val successful = Promise[List[T]]()     //Create a promise which will be returning the results
 successful.success(Nil)
```

would't this complete the promise and therefore will not allow you the write to the promise any further? Which will also trigger the promises onComplete callback?

The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to understand the following piece of code and I am trying to understand why the promise was initialised with a Nil before the computation on the future even start.

```
def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = {
  val successful = Promise[List[T]]()     //Create a promise which will be returning the results
  successful.success(Nil)                 //Initialize the profile
  fs.foldRight(successful.future) {       //Create the Aggregate for the fold right which will be an empty future
    //for each element extract the element from the future and append to our aggregate
    //f -> Future[T] acc -> Future[List[T]]
    (f, acc) => for { x <- f; xs <- acc } yield x :: xs
  }
}
```

Thinking out aloud I would say the reason for completing the promise is that there are no callbacsk attached and therefore we don't care when it succeeds. If so the only reason were using a promise is to make use of it's future. So isn't their a simpler/cleaner way to define a future without making use of a promise which we actually don't need?

Comment: In this case it's needed in order to handle the case where `fs` is empty.

Comment: so let's say the fs is not null. Will the foldright trigger the onComplete callback on the promise since it was already set due to the previous success?

Comment: there is no call to 'onComplete' to register a callback.

Comment: Empty and null are not the same thing.  `fs` is a list and if you call `foldRight` on an empty list you'll get an exception.  In this case, there are no `onComplete` callbacks, only combinators that return new futures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a promise is only completed once (I'm not sure what you mean by "onComplete callback", I don't see such a thing in the standard library `Promise` docs). But of course the promise's `future` is available and works as expected even if the promise has already been completed. This looks to be an overcomplicated way of using `Future.successful(Nil)` as the initial element for the `foldRight`.

Comment: sorry by onComplete I was referring to the onSuccess method of the promise, which isn't any where in the code but it was just a hypothetical question.

So to make sure I understand you correctly the 

successful.success(Nil)   

Initialised the future: Future[List[T]] to Nil which will be basically used in the foldRight.

Is there anyway to write the following code in a more elegant manner?

Comment: You could write the code as `fs.foldRight(Future.successful(List[T]())) { ...`. More elegantly the whole function is just `fs.sequence` if you use Scalaz and have an `implicit ExecutionContext` in scope (at least, I *think* scalaz comes with an `Applicative[Future]` somewhere).